# How to save, and then serve again data of type io.Reader?

Tags: go

I would like to parse several times with [`gocal`](http://github.com/apognu/gocal) data I retrieve through a HTTP call. Since I would like to avoid making the call for each of the parsing, I would like to save this data and reuse it.

The `Body` I get from [`http.Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Get) is of type `io.ReadCloser`. The [`gocal` parser](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apognu/gocal@v0.8.0#NewParser) requires `io.Reader` so it works.

Since I can retrieve `Body` only once,  I can save it with `body, _ := io.ReadAll(get.Body)` but then I do not know how to serve `[]byte` as `io.Reader` back (to the `gocal` parser, several times to account for different parsing conditions)

Comment: Use bytes.NewReader

Comment: https://godoc.org/bytes#NewReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have figured, the `http.Response.Body` is exposed as an `io.Reader`, this reader is not re usable because [it is connected straight to the underlying connection](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/net/http/transport.go;l=2280;drc=master)* (might be [tcp](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn)/[utp](https://github.com/anacrolix/go-libutp)/or any other [stream like reader](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn) under the [net](https://pkg.go.dev/net) package).
Once you read the bytes out of the connection, new bytes are sitting their waiting for another read.

In order to save the response, indeed, you need to drain it first, and save that result within a variable.

`body, _ := io.ReadAll(get.Body)`

To re use that slice of bytes many time using the Go programming language, the standard API provides a buffered reader [`bytes.NewReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#NewReader).

This buffer adequately offers the [`Reset([]byte)`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Reader.Reset) method to reset the state of the buffer.

The [`bytes.Reader.Reset`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/bytes/reader.go;l=157) is very useful to read multiple times the same bytes buffer with no allocations. In comparison, [`bytes.NewReader`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/bytes/reader.go;l=160) allocates every time it is called.

Finally, between two consecutive calls to `c.Parser`, you should reset the buffer with bytes buffer you have collected previously.

such as :

```golang
buf := bytes.NewReader(body)
// initialize the parser
c.Parse()
// process the result

// reset the buf, parse again
buf.Reset(body)
c.Parse()
```

You can try this version https://play.golang.org/p/YaVtCTZHZEP It uses the `strings.NewReader` buffer, but the interface and behavior are similar.

- not super obvious, that is the general principle, the transport reads the headers, and leave the body untouched unless you consume it. see also [that](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/net/http/transfer.go;drc=master;l=483).